# Transcendental Equation

Tags: python, equation

I've faced a task to solve a transcendental equation:

```
K = K0*(exp(-t*B)/1+L*B)
```

Variable 'B' is unknown. I have to take the next expression for B for a first step:

```
B = (K0-1)/(L+t)
```

For the second step and for all the next steps I have to calculate B as:

```
B = -(1/t)*ln((1+L*B)/K0)
```

The iteration stops when relative difference between the previous and the current value for B doesn't exceed, say, 1%. The resulting B should make the first equation right part be equal to 1.
How can I do it with python? I've heard about zero-finding routines from scipy, but I really would prefer some ordinary coding (It would help me to understand things better). I've tried the while loop. I can write a loop to iterate and stop iterating when K from the first equation is close enough to 1.0:

```
kinf = 1.123456e+00

tau = 2.832995e+01

L2 = 3.745903e+00

i = 1

b2 = (kinf-1)/(L2+tau)

def iterate():
    b = b2
    i = 1
    print "iteration no.{:.1f}; B^2 = {:.06e}; delta = {:.03f}".format(i, b, kinf*((exp(-tau*b))/(1+L2*b)) - 1.0)
    while abs(kinf*((exp(-tau*b))/(1+L2*b))-1.0)>0.0001:
        b = -(1/tau)*log((1+L2*b)/kinf)
        i+=1
        print "iteration no.{:.1f}; B^2 = {:.06e}; delta = {:.03f}".format(i, b, kinf*((exp(-tau*b))/(1+L2*b)) - 1.0)
```

But I can't understand, how do I compare previous and current values of B. I suppose, this problem is one of classic ones, but I appreciate any help.

UPD:
Thank you for your help!
Am I doing it right now?

```
def iterate():
b0 = (kinf-1)/(L2+tau)
bold = b0
b = -(1/tau)*log((1+L2*b0)/kinf)
bnew = b
diff = ((bnew-bold)/bnew)*100
while abs(diff)>=0.01:
    print 'previous B^2 = {:.06e}'.format(bold)
    bnew = -(1/tau)*log((1+L2*bold)/kinf)
    print 'B^2 = {:.06e}'.format(bnew)
    diff = ((bnew-bold)/bnew)*100
    print 'delta = {:.06e}'.format(diff)
    bold = bnew
```

Comment: You'd normally create a temporary variable for this kind of case. e.g. `old_b=b` before changing the value of `b` in the loop

Comment: Where do you need to do the comparison?

Comment: I calculate the first approach for B like that: B = (K0-1)/(L+t), than I need to start calculating next approaches for B like: B = -(1/t)*ln((1+L*B)/K0) and compare each new B with the previous one, until they're close enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't override `b` in this line (you'll loose the old value of `b` this way):

```
b = -(1/tau)*log((1+L2*b)/kinf) # the old value of b gets lost here
```

Instead you can do this within your `while`-loop:

```
b_new = -(1/tau)*log((1+L2*b)/kinf)
b_delta = b_new - b
# do whatever you want with b_delta and finally override the old b with the new b
b = b_new
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this while iteration you can create a `previous_b` variable and initialize it to `None`. Then in your while loop, continue if previous_b is None **or** difference is greater than your threshold.

```
kinf = 1.123456e+00

tau = 2.832995e+01

L2 = 3.745903e+00

i = 1

b2 = (kinf-1)/(L2+tau)

def iterate():
    previous_b = None
    b = b2
    i = 1
    print "iteration no.{:.1f}; B^2 = {:.06e}; delta = {:.03f}".format(i, b, kinf*((exp(-tau*b))/(1+L2*b)) - 1.0)
    while previous_b is None or abs(kinf*((exp(-tau*b))/(1+L2*b))-1.0)>0.0001:
        previous_b = b
        b = -(1/tau)*log((1+L2*b)/kinf)
        i+=1
        print "iteration no.{:.1f}; B^2 = {:.06e}; delta = {:.03f}".format(i, b, kinf*((exp(-tau*b))/(1+L2*b)) - 1.0)
```