# Use sympy to solve a transcendental equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Experienced with Python. New to Sympy.

I have a transcendental equation, f(x) = sin(x) - x.

If y = f(x), I want to solve for x knowing y.

I think Sympy can do this, but I have no experience with it. Can someone explain what I should do?

(The question [Transcendental Equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263965/transcendental-equation) has answers for hand-rolling the iterative approach, which is my back-up.)

Here is what I have tried:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
solve(Eq(sin(x) - x))  # Exception raised here

# NotImplementedError: multiple generators [x, sin(x)]
# No algorithms are implemented to solve equation -x + sin(x)
```

I recognize this does not even communicate that I have a known value for y. As you can see, I don't understand what to do at all.

This would be an iterative solution. Is there a way to get sympy to do this, or should I be using a different Python package for iterative solutions?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Sympy does symbolic math. That's what it's named for. If you want a numerical solution, sympy is not the tool for the job.

Comment: Thank you, but when I look here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Quick-examples I see the solve function returns results of a list of numbers -- the roots of that polynomial equation. That's what led me to believe I could do this.

Comment: x=0 is the only real solution ... In any case, what about newton's, bisection or any other good root finding method?

Comment: Add my known value to the equation and it shifts the roots to be the answers I am looking for.  Newton's method or bisection are what I am referring to when I say "hand-rolling the iterative approach". It would be nice if such a common operation is in some package somewhere so I don't have to lug around my own hand-roll in a gist.

Comment: The polynomials on that page are solvable symbolically; sympy is not resorting to numerical methods. Your equation is not solvable symbolically.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I have been doing more websearch since I posted the original question. It looks like I need scipy.optimize.fsolve?  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#scipy.optimize.fsolve

Comment: From another question/answer: fsolve "is a multi-dimensional root-finder, this [may add] overhead." Other approaches are available and may be faster, including bisect and newton. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937643/solve-highly-non-linear-equation-for-x-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using [nsolve](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.nsolve)? ie:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> nsolve(sin(x)-x, x, 1)
```

It seems it uses [mpmath.findroot](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/modules/mpmath/calculus/optimization.html#mpmath.findroot) behind the curtains.